Ubuntu locking up during boot
When I try to boot Ubuntu, it appears to lock up during the boot process. If I reboot using the recovery boot, I can get in, but cannot seem to boot cleanly.
I have an HP Laptop 15 currently using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, a 64-bit system using GNOME version 42.9. The problem started under Ubuntu 18.
I have a Windows partition, but the boot is set to start Ubuntu by default.
I have booted Windows, updated everything there, downloaded the latest HP BIOS and updated that. I've run HP diagnostics both in Windows and from the grub options. All the diagnostics come back clean.
I've run ClamTK on the directories and they come up clean.
Then I tried updating Ubuntu to 22.04.4 LTS hoping that would fix something in the OS itself. No joy.
Checking the logs I get:
08:16:43 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
08:16:36 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
08:16:33 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
08:16:16 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
08:16:16 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
08:16:16 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
08:16:15 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
08:16:15 gnome-session-b: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
08:16:15 gnome-session-b: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
08:16:14 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
08:16:14 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
08:14:44 systemd: Failed to start GNOME Shell on Wayland.
08:14:35 pulseaudio: Found duplicated D-Bus path for device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_90_EE_C7_5B_02_EE
08:14:35 pulseaudio: Found duplicated D-Bus path for device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_90_EE_C7_5B_02_EE
08:14:35 pulseaudio: Found duplicated D-Bus path for adapter /org/bluez/hci0
08:13:51 (sd-executor): /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/friendly-recovery failed with exit status 1.
08:11:54 avahi-daemon: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
08:11:47 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.WLBU._STA.WLVD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.WLBU._STA.WLVD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q42 due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.ESDT due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20210730/exfldio-261)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RCM0] (00000000adddcade) [SystemCMOS] (20210730/evregion-130)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.WLBU._STA.WLVD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WLBU._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.WLBU._STA.WLVD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
08:11:26 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP2.BCM5], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)

I've about run out of ideas before I go sudo'ing things and really get myself in a jam. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Is it better now?
